# Filter a log file by month, date and time in bash

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, logs

I'd like to fetch the data between `Apr 24 10:00:00.000000` and `Apr 25 24:00:00.999999` in the following log but I am not sure how to get this work:

```
files/file1:Apr 22 02:47:00.663117 somedata    
files/file1:Apr 23 04:47:00.663127 somedata    
files/file1:Apr 24 05:47:00.663137 somedata    
files/file1:Apr 24 10:47:00.663137 somedata    
files/file1:Apr 25 01:47:00.663147 somedata    
files/file1:Apr 25 23:47:00.663157 somedata    
files/file1:Apr 25 23:47:00.663167 somedata    
files/file1:Apr 26 23:47:00.663177 somedata
```

I tried using the following command but that would only filter by time and not consider date as well:

```
awk -v start=10:00:00.000000 -v stop=24:00:00.999999 'start <= $3 && $3 <= stop'
```

I would like only the following data to be fetched:

```
files/file1:Apr 24 10:47:00.663137 somedata    
files/file1:Apr 25 01:47:00.663147 somedata    
files/file1:Apr 25 23:47:00.663157 somedata    
files/file1:Apr 25 23:47:00.663167 somedata
```

Can someone please help with this? Also, it would be very useful to consider month as well while filtering

Comment: You meant up to `April 25 23:59:59.99999` ?

Comment: ohhh yeah i meant 23:59:59.999999 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can very simply add more variables for the day filter:

```
awk -v start_day=24 -v stop_day=25 -v start_time=10:00:00.000000 -v stop_time=24:00:00.999999 'start_day <= $2 && $2 <= stop_day && start_time <= $3 && $3 <= stop_time' file
```

yields

```
files/file1:Apr 24 10:47:00.663137 somedata    
files/file1:Apr 25 23:47:00.663157 somedata    
files/file1:Apr 25 23:47:00.663167 somedata
```

we're missing a line for Apr 25 because we blindly filter the time to be under 10am. All we have to do is implement a logical test to filter time only for the first day:

```
awk -v start_day=24 -v stop_day=25 -v start_time=05:00:00.000000 -v stop_time=05:00:00.999999 'start_day <= $2 && $2 <= stop_day && (start_time <= $3 || start_day != $2) && $3 <= stop_time' file
```

yields

```
files/file1:Apr 24 10:47:00.663137 somedata    
files/file1:Apr 25 01:47:00.663147 somedata    
files/file1:Apr 25 23:47:00.663157 somedata    
files/file1:Apr 25 23:47:00.663167 somedata
```

For months you can follow the same idea but you need to translate Apr to 04 (pre-processing or awk magic?) and apply <= => on that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What does this actually do? (start_time <= $3 || start_day != $2)

Comment: Filter the time only for the first day

Comment: It's supposed to work and after testing it seems to work too. The full version of the command being:

    `awk -v start_day=24 -v stop_day=25 -v start_time=10:00:00.000000 -v stop_time=24:00:00.999999 'start_day <= $2 && $2 <= stop_day && (start_time <= $3 || start_day != $2) && $3 <= stop_time' file`

Comment: when I executed this:  awk -v start_day=24 -v stop_day=25 -v start_time=05:00:00.000000 -v stop_time=05:00:00.999999 'start_day <= $2 && $2 <= stop_day && (start_time <= $3 || start_day != $2) && $3 <= stop_time' tempFile
it displays just "Apr 25 01:47:00.663147 somedata"

Comment: Oh right, if you want to filter the time on the end date then here you go:

``awk -v start_day=24 -v stop_day=25 -v start_time=05:00:00.000000 -v stop_time=05:00:00.999999 'start_day <= $2 && $2 <= stop_day && (start_time <= $3 || start_day != $2) && (stop_day != $2 || $3 <= stop_time)' file``

Comment: How can I consider months in the filter?

Comment: Even if I translate Apr to 04 and May to 05, the logs would still have Apr and May in it. How do I get logs between Apr and May only in a log that has March and June data as well ? Would it be possible to filter by month, day and time in a similar way as in case of filtering by day and time?

Comment: :) gt it to wrk